# Como redirecionar um subdomínio usando o serviço de DNS do Registro.br

Tags: servidor, redes, dns, redirecionamento-de-url

Tenho um servidor particular com IP fixo e possuo alguns sites rodando na porta 80.

Configuração: Linux Debian e Apache

Por exemplo, tenho dois subdomínios:

```
IP_SERVIDOR/site1
IP_SERVIDOR/site2
```

Fiz o registro dos dois domínios no registro.br: "www.site1.com.br" e "www.site2.com.br".

Estou utilizando os serviços de DNS do próprio registro.br. Gostaria de saber como uso a Edição de zona DNS para redirecionar cada subdomínio. Ou seja:

```
www.site1.com.br -> IP_SERVIDOR/site1
www.site2.com.br -> IP_SERVIDOR/site2
```

O máximo que eu consegui é configurar o tipo "A" na edição de zona do DNS no registro.br.

```
Para o site1
www.site1.com.br    A    IP_SERVIDOR

Para o site2
www.site2.com.br    A    IP_SERVIDOR
```

Ou seja, ambos os sites irão apontar para a raiz. No meu caso irão cair na raiz da pasta `www`. Acredito que o resto da configuração seria no servidor Apache.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Esta configuração é dependente de tecnologia. Qual a tecnologia de servidores você está usando?

Comment: Uso linux Debian, servidor apache e os sites são feitos em PHP. Sou um pouco leigo em relação a redes e servidores. Não sei, por exemplo, se é correto chamar "/site1" e "/site2" de subdomínio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso implica alterar as configurações do servidor web que utiliza. Em caso de apache, são os VirtualHosts.

Fica aqui um link do site do apache, com instruções acerca de como proceder: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html

Na configuração de DNS só é preciso uma linha, que associa o nome do domínio ao IP, do tipo A. O resto pode ser tudo configurado no seu servidor, desde HTTP a email e outras aplicações.

Relativamente aos virtualhosts, é necessário criar / editar o ficheiro de configuração do apache que tem essas configurações, e colocar qualquer coisa semelhante a isto (não testado):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /www/site1
ServerName www.site1.com.br
# Other directives here
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /www/site2
ServerName www.site2.com.br
# Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```

Nunca esquecer mecanismos de segurança no acesso aos ficheiros e outras coisas a ter em conta quando se configura uma pasta para servir de root a um site. O facto de nos exemplos estar uma linha que diz "# Other directives here", é porque devem estar mesmo!

Comment: Editei minha pergunta, acredito que esta mais completa.

Comment: @AlanValejo o resto da configuração é mesmo no apache. o primeiro exemplo do link que deixei na minha resposta serve para o caso.

Comment: Entendi. Eu consigo uma configuração mais simples apenas incluindo um .htaccess na raiz da pasta www com algumas regras?

Comment: @AlanValejo isto não está relacionado com .htaccess Podes usar .htaccess para outros fins, mas a forma correcta de fazer esta configuração é no apache.

Comment: Acho que a configuração pelo VirtualHost esta bem intuitiva. Vou tentar aqui.

Comment: não estou conseguindo descobrir qual arquivo modificar, em alguns lugares dizem para mexer em `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` outros `/etc/apache2/sites-enable/` outros em `/etc/httpd/...` e assim por diante. Qual arquivo/lugar é o certo?

Comment: @AlanValejo o ficheiro existente em /etc/apache2/sites-enabled por norma é apenas um link para o /etc/apache2/sites-available. Penso que em debian é nessas pastas e nao em /etc/httpd, mas verifica a existência das pastas e dos ficheiros.